# How can I use data.table or data.csv and extra data for click event handling

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart built using a data.table (HTML table). http://jsfiddle.net/m78Lwkqt/2/

I want to use a 3rd column of the table to drive a click to a particular URL.

```
       series:[
        {             
          type: 'pie',
          animation: false,
          point:{
              events:{
                  click: 
                      function (event) 
                      {
                          // I want to get the 3rd column of the table's value
                          // that corresponds to this point.
                          alert(this.y);
                      }
                  }
              }          
       }
       ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanreid22/m78Lwkqt/4/

The trick is to add a seriesMapping value (in this case I've called it 'accountCode') that can be used in the point.click handler.

```
data: {
            table: 'smry_t_pb_outlay_by_account',
            seriesMapping: [{
                 x: 0, // X values are pulled from column 0 by default
                 y: 1, // Y values are pulled from column 1 by default
                accountCode: 2 // used in the point.click below
            }]
        },

events: {
        click:
            function (event) {
                alert(this.accountCode);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery selector to get all the `td`s from the third column, and when needed match `this.x` from this click event up against the array you got from the jQuery selector.

For example, getting the third column using a jQuery selector:

```
var thirdColumn = $("#smry_t_pb_outlay_by_account tr td:nth-child(3)");
```

And then using this array inside your `point.events.click` to get the data:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            alert(thirdColumn[this.x].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/m78Lwkqt/3/) of the code.